# My required field in my form HTML doesn´t work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have created a  in HTML with required fields and then a Submit button with a ng-click=add().

The code is the following:

Enter name:

```
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label class="form-label">Enter surname:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Person surname" ng-model= "newPerson.surname" required>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label class="form-label">Enter age:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Person age" ng-model= "newPerson.age" required>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
      <label class="form-label">Enter occupation:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Person occupation" ng-model= "newPerson.occupation" required>
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add()">Add</button>
    
</form>
```

When pressing the button, it adds the person and then it tells me that the fields are required but in my list the person is already there will undefined values.

I have declared  on top of the document as well.

Thanks

Comment: Call `add()` on submit, not on the button click.

Comment: Sorry but where do you mean with "on submit" ? Thanks

Comment: Thank you I have just found out the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can as well use a validation method to validate the inputs on submission instead of required.
example

```js
public validateForm() {
  if(newPerson.surname === null || 
  newPerson.surname === undefined || newPerson.surname === " ")
  {
    error.surname = "Surname is required";
  }
  if(newPerson.age === null || 
  newPerson.age === undefined || newPerson.age === " ")
  {
    error.age = "Age is required";
  }
  if(newPerson.occupation === null || 
  newPerson.occupation === undefined || newPerson.occupation === " ")
  {
    error.occupation = "Occupation is required";
  }
  
  if(newPerson.surname !== null || 
  newPerson.surname !== undefined || newPerson.surname !== " " ||
  newPerson.age !== null || 
  newPerson.age !== undefined || newPerson.age !== " " ||
  newPerson.occupation !== null || 
  newPerson.occupation !== undefined || newPerson.occupation !== "
  )
  {
    this.add();
  }

}
```

```html
  <div class="mb-3">
      <label class="form-label">Enter surname:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Person surname" ng-model= "newPerson.surname" required>
    </div>
    <span *ngIf="error.surname"> {{error.surname}}</span>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label class="form-label">Enter age:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Person age" ng-model= "newPerson.age" required>
    </div>
    <span *ngIf="error.age"> {{error.age}}</span>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label class="form-label">Enter occupation:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Person occupation" ng-model= "newPerson.occupation" required>
    </div>
    <span *ngIf="error.occupation"> {{error.occupation}}</span>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="validateForm()">Add</button>
    
</form>
```